# SSIS...How do i run SQL script inside SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

So my question is how do I take a table that populates QC(quality control) SQL scripts and then have them run within SSIS, so that I can have flags set regarding each SQL Script.

There are 15 total scripts that check different things, so I will need to loop through them each.

--example--

Id |          SQL_Statment                             | Bypass
1  |Select count(*) from "" where firstName is null;   | 0

2  |Select count(*) from "" where lastName is null;    | 1

Depending on if those scripts are true or false I will need to set flags to later place back in another table.

Is this even possible and how would I approach it.

Answer (score 0):

@Liqudid715

Not sure if I understand your question.  Also, for SO, what you should be doing is showing what you have already tried and why it didn't work.

There is an execute SQL task that you can use in control flow items to run the scripts.  Set the result set to single row.  Create a user variable, and set the user variable based on the result (Result set, with result name being 0).  Then you can use the variable in another execute sql task to update another table.

I dont know what you mean by loop through, but you can connect all of the execute sql tasks, but if you are using them to set variable, I don't think you would need to do that.